# How to force a layout to entend across the whole screen

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am creating an android app and I am currently creating the graphics.  However, my LinearLayout does not take up the whole screen, cutting off some of the words that need to be displayed.  For example, [image: this] is what is displayed.  My xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.root.layouts.Main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="y"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/years"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text=":"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="m"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/months"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text=":"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="w"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/weeks"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text=":"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="d"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/days"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text=":"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="h"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/hours"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text=":"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="m"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/minutes"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text=":"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="s"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/seconds"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!-- I think this is where the problem starts -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Years"
                android:rotation="270"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Months"
                android:rotation="270"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Weeks"
                android:rotation="270"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Days"
                android:rotation="270"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Hours"
                android:rotation="270"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Minutes"
                android:rotation="270"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Seconds"
                android:rotation="270"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Much of this is probably not relevant, but I want to make sure that I include all that is needed.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the heights of the many nested LinearLayouts you have. The root view should have a height of: `android:height="match_parent"` to fill the screen. Having this many nested LinearLayouts is also bad for performance. Have a look at some of the other ViewGroup classes (FrameLayout, RelativeLayout, etc) that should allow you to achieve the UI you want more effectivly. [Android ViewGroup Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)

Answer (score 0):

#1. You probably don't need all those views. You certainly don't need every piece of text to be wrapped in its own `LinearLayout`. So far the most you'd need is

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <!-- more textviews with same layout params -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <!-- more textviews with same layout params -->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can probably optimize this even more if you use something like [`GridLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html).

#2. A lot of people misunderstand what `android:rotation` does. It only affects how the view is *drawn*; it does not affect how the view is *measured* and *laid out*. The problem is your `TextView`s are measured and laid out as if the text were not rotated, and then the text is drawn rotated, so the text gets cut off.

I don't know any simple solution to this. The only idea I have is to extend `TextView`and override `onMeasure()` to do something hacky like this:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // swap the measure specs
    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    // swap the resulting measured dimensions
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
}
```

I have no idea how well this will work; in fact, I can almost guarantee it will be buggy (for one thing, your left and right padding will be treated as top and bottom padding, and vice versa), but it should illustrate the point. You may try looking online for a better implementation of `TextView` that can draw its text upwards and downwards.